# Delete character at specific position with regex in vscode

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code

I have multiple file logs from a telephone switchboard, recently the dialing way changed in my phone operator, now there is no need to dial 0 for long distance calls.

```
example: 
original
12/12/16 15:25    *345 46 78968752                     00:06'23
12/12/16 15:26     516 57 72668547                     00:07'31 
12/12/16 15:27     468 03 048846587                    00:09'34 
12/12/16 15:28    *516 08 058846587                    00:03'45 

replace with
12/12/16 15:25    *345 46 78968752                     00:06'23 
12/12/16 15:26     516 57 72668547                     00:07'31 
12/12/16 15:27     468 03 48846587                     00:09'34 
12/12/16 15:28    *516 08 58846587                     00:03'45
```

Therefore I have to find all 0 in position 27 and delete them moving forward all the following numbers. What the correct regex and the replacement todo that?

Comment: I realized i cannot move the call duration position (last numbers of the line) , this regex is getting very complex.

Comment: If you don't want the call duration position to move, you can replace the zero with a space. Will that work for you?

Comment: So you mean now that the removed 0 must be replaced by a space after the phone number?

Comment: Exactly, remove the 0 and insert a space after the number, which size may vary. Call duration always start at position 58 though.

Comment: I think that if you don't want to count the positions you might match a "datetime like" pattern followed by the 2 and 3 digits and replace with the first capturing group `^(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\*?\d{3}\s+\d{2}\s+)0+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/anpvT6/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your phone number is always 8 digits after an optional 0 then this regex works:

https://regex101.com/r/OLgGOx/1

```
0(\d{8})
```

and replace with `$1`

After your comment below `0(\d{2,8})` works.

Or try

```
  (^[\S\s]{26})(0?)(.*)
```

to explicitly remove the 27th character if it is a 0.

Replace with `$1$3`

After your comment above try:

```
(^[\S\s]{26})(?:(0)([\d]*)(\s))
```

replace with:

```
$1$3$4$4
```

[unfortunately I don't have the time to explain that further until tomorrow.]

Basically it uses the trick of conditionally capturing a single space - group 4 - is there is a 0 in the 27th position.  And then adding an additional group 4.  This works because if there was no 0 in position 27, groups 2, 3 and 4 are empty anyway.

See https://regex101.com/r/OLgGOx/2

and enable the `PCRE2` setting in vscode.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, not all numbers in the log has 8 digits, that was just an example. what I need is to delete only the 0 characters at position 27.

Comment: Well, how many digits might they have?  Surely there is a range - as long as it is more than 1 the regex could be easily changed to work

Comment: I don't usually ask for an upvote, but I did provide three working regex's as the target moved!  ;>}  Thanks.  And I learned a little about faking a conditional replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
(\*\d{3}\s\d{2}\s)\[0\]+
```

[image]